# Verilog : For loop inside an always

Tags: verilog

I am trying to implement a module that use a for loop inside a always block
We are using an array of 0 & 1 in order to record the number of signal received during a certain time.

Unfortunatly we received that kind of error :

```
ERROR:Xst:2636 - "Tourniquet.v" line 54: Loop has iterated 10000 times. Use "set -loop_iteration_limit XX" to iterate more.
```

It seems that the for loop isn't allowed inside a always block (The n doesn't seems to reset).
I have looked at various website and forum but don't have found any solutions.

Here is my code :

```
  module Tourniquet(
    input t0,
    input mvt,
     input clk,
    output init
    );

reg initialisation;
reg [0:99] memoire;
reg count = 0;
reg compteur = 0;
reg n;

assign init = initialisation;

always @(posedge clk) 
begin
    if (count==99) 
    begin 
            if (mvt)
            begin 
            memoire[count]=1;
            count=0;
            end

            else
            begin 
            memoire[count]=0;
            count=0;
            end
    end 

    else
    begin 
            if (mvt)
            begin 
            memoire[count]=1;
            count = count + 1;
            end

            else
            begin 
            memoire[count]=0;
            count = count + 1;
            end
    end
end

always @(posedge clk) 
begin
initialisation = 0;
for (n=0; n<99; n=n+1) compteur = compteur + memoire[n];
if (compteur>10) initialisation = 1;
compteur = 0;
end

endmodule
```

I can't find the solution nor be sure of what is the problem, any tips or help is welcomed.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the loop to iterate 100 times. For that, you need **atleast 8 bit counter variable**.

But here, `n` is declared as `reg n`, a single bit counter variable. So, `n+1` gives `1` and doing `n+1` again gives `0`.

So, the condition  of for loop for which `n<100` is **always satisfied**. And the for loop **never terminates**.

This is the main reason your for loop iterates many many times.

Generally `integer` datatype is used for these kind of counters. `integer` is similar to 32 bit `reg`. Declare `n` as `integer n` or `reg [7:0] n` to have **proper increment of counter** and proper termination of loop.

Answer (score 4):

Further to @sharvil111's answer, I see *all* these are single bits:

```
reg initialisation;
reg count = 0;
reg compteur = 0;
reg n;
```

An N bit `reg` in Verilog is normally declared, eg:

```
reg [N-1:0] n;
```

where N is some number (constant). And I see this is a 100-bit number:

```
reg [0:99] memoire;
```

Obviously, I don't know your design intent, but I suspect you wanted an array of N-bit numbers:

```
reg [N-1:0] memoire [0:99];
```

where N is again some number (constant).